# Node Async - Execute 2 sequencial query for an array of object

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, promise, async-await

Below code is working but I recognize that it is horrible and unmaintainable.

I have an array of dates and I need to run 2 queries, the first to generate the next number in the database and the second to insert the new event into the database.

How can I perform this routine with a better code? I believe I can use async / await (es7) or promise or callbacks.

```
const async = require('async')

function Reschedule(){

this.createEvent = function(req, res, next){
    req.DesiredDate = req.DesiredDate.filter(e=>e.Available)
    // req.DesiredDate = [{},{},{}.....] objects with date property desired 
    async.forEachSeries((req.DesiredDate), function (item, callback){

      conn.acquire(function(err,con){
        con.query('SELECT EventID, EventCode FROM event WHERE YEAR(StartEvent) = YEAR(?) order by eventId desc limit 1', [item.dateStart], function(err, result) {
          con.release();
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.render('error', { error: err } );
          }else{


//Get new Number of EVENT

            let eventCode = result.length === 0  ? parseInt(moment(item.dateStart).year() + '0001') : result[0].EventCode + 1
            console.log('proximo codigo: ' + eventCode)

            let newEvent = {
              Type: 'I',
              EventCode: eventCode,
              StartEvent: item.dateStart,
              EndEvent: item.dateEnd,
              Room_ID: req.findEventByCode.RoomID,
              Name: req.findEventByCode.title
            }

// after get new number in query above, then create new event

            conn.acquire(function(err,con){
              con.query('INSERT INTO Event SET ?', [newEvent], function(err, result) {
                con.release()
                if(err) {
                  console.log(err)
                  res.render('error', { error: err })
                } else {
                  console.log('created new event ' + eventCode);
                  callback()
                }
              })
            })
          }
        })
      })
    }, function(err) {
      next()
    })
  }
}
module.exports = new Reschedule()
```

Answer (score 0):

the whole point of promises and async in javascript is to do something and when its done, do something with the response without you needing to wait. so a good example could be:

```
function get_event(){
  //this functions gets data
  return "Some data";
}

function create_event(data){
  //function that does something
  var do_something = (d) => {
    console.log(d);
    return true;
  }
  //return that function
  return do_something(data);
}

async function query(){
  //execute as async
  return await create_event(get_event());
}


query().then((callback_data) => {
  //do stuff with callback data
  console.log(callback_data); //prints true
});
```

and if we want to go overkill (not recommended) :

```
async function get_event(){
  //this functions gets data
  return "Some data";
}

async function create_event(data){
  //function that does something
  var do_something = (d) => {
    console.log(d);
    return true;
  }
  //return that function
  return await do_something(data);
}

async function query(){
  //execute as async
  return await get_event().then((data) => {
    return create_event(data).then((callback_data) => {
        return callback_data;
    });
});
}


query().then((callback_data) => {
  //do stuff with callback data
  console.log(callback_data); //prints true
});
```

so i will recommend you to split up the tasks into separate functions and call them together in an asynchronous function.

> NOTE: if the goal is to make the code easier to maintain.